# Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host

Tags: android, android-studio

Obtengo este error al momento de compilar la applicacion en android studio 4.1.1, reinicio, ya he realizado la mayoria de soluciones que encuentro en internet pero siempre falla y vuelve aparecer
**Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host.**

La unica manera de solucion que he encontrado hasta el momento es, reiniciar el computador y abrir android studio, este paso de reiniicar el computador y abrir, lo repito hasta que se quite esa falla.

Quisiera saber si hay una solucion efectiva que me quite ese problema, en veces tardo hasta una hora tratando de iniciar android studio.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Yo tambien tenía el mismo problema. Basicamente lo que hice fue actualizar mi IDE. Luego de reiniciar la maquina todo bien.

[image: IDE and plugin update: en configuraciones -> check for update]

Comment: @Kenny Barrera ya aprendi que la palabra correcta es actualizar. Podrias quitar el (-1) por favor.

Comment: Yo no te di el -1, solo te ayude un poco a editar la respuesta y cambiar la palabra. Pero si puedo decirte que, por alguna extraña razon, aqui dan muchos negativos por publicaciones con imagenes, y no termino de entender porque. Pero te regalo un +1 para que no te desanimes y continues participando y contestando.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. En la comunidad en ingles no pasa eso, que raro.

Answer (score -1):

Este vinculo me ayudo. Tenia el mismo problema con Visual Basic 2013
https://anothercoffee.net/fix-error-code-2013-lost-connection-mysql-server-query/

Comment: Escribe un breve resumen (pulsando en [edit]) del contenido del enlace que proporcionas: recuerda que tal contenido puede que no esté disponible más adelante, volviendo a esta respuesta como inválida. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.